# Can I make macro Excel files without enabling the macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro Excel file (xlsm extension), that I want it to run on any PC without making the user enabling/trusting the macro in it.
PS: this is only because the file contains multiple forms that needs to be filled with some restrictions, for example case sometimes need to be a number with a pre-defined length, or a string , etc.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If macros are not enabled/trusted, they won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as a security feature of Excel it should prompt you to enable content to prevent harmful codes from being run in spreadsheets. What you're asking for is a bypass through security, which should not exist.

This was a topic covered in the [MREXCEL Forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/968366-vba-macro-enable-content-document.html)

You can however, keep the sheet locked until they enable content which will then unlock the sheet as a proxy to twist their arm into enabling content.

Comment: Thank you dear,
However, can you please explain to me what do you mean by saying "keep the sheet locked until they enable content which will then unlock the sheet as a proxy to twist their arm into enabling content. "
I just need the macro to run without the user enabling it (the form that I'm trying to send to customers needs the macro to run) 
Thanks again

Comment: You can't make a macro that bypasses security measures. But if you write a code that locks all the spreadsheets on closing and unlocks it when it's opened, they won't be able to interact with the sheet until they enable macros. This is a hacky workaround that forces the user to enable macros if they want to use the sheet.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, you're a savior !